# How to increase the detection speed of yolov3 as it takes 6 seconds to know the correct class?

Tags: object, deep-learning, yolo

Tried to change the color to gray but that didn't help so much:
ImageGray = cv2.cvtColor(image,BGR2GRAY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question.
Try

1. resizing the images to a smaller size: reduce dataset resolution.
2. use GPU